# Dynamically define Hub methods in SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

Is it possibly to dynamically create Hub methods in SignalR? I want to create some Hub methods that provide completely the same logic, just with different types. Is it possible to dynamically add the Hub methods on hub creation or something like that?

I am looking for something similar to the On-Methods on SignalR clients, just server-side.

Comment: Smells a little fishy passing in types. If else...if else...if else...Look into conditional to polymorphism and use one class. Then you won't have to worry about creating dynamic methods, which I don't think you can do. Another option may be to use generics in your hub.

Comment: Yeah i know i could use if/else, i probably could also serialize stuff as strings and deserialize it manually, but that is not exactly what i was looking for. Polymorphism does not work in this situation at all. I not only need different types as parameters, but i also need different types in the logic of the event handlers, types that are not known on the client
I know that i will need some generics, but how can i use them in my hub?